# Mongoose findById check if property exist

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Mongoose model such as;

```
var Schema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  subtitle: { type: String, required: true },
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String, name: String, size: Number, encoding: String }
```

});

I perform a

```
let projection = "image";
Model.findById(req.params.id,projection, function (err, doc) {
  console.log(err);
  if (err) {
    res.status(422).json(err);
  }
  else {
    res.contentType(doc.image.contentType);
    res.send(doc.image.data);
  }
});
```

I get the error stating that can not read property and the problem is there is no image property stored in the record. How can I ignore this, it should not matter if an image is stored or not.

Thanx in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check in the callback if `doc` is `undefined`.  If it is, return some other message/status, if it is not, return the image.

For Example:

```
Model.findById(..., function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {...}
    else if (doc.image) {<return the image here>}
    else {<return a no image found message>}
}
```

For even more safety, you should probably check that `doc` is defined first, since it's possible to return an empty array/object, which would cause the `(doc.image)` check to fail.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized this. Do I have to check if document exist? Should't that be covered in my first err check statement?

Comment: No, the err is just that, an error, as in it couldn't connect to the db or some other failure.  If everything is successful, but it doesn't find anything, it will just bring back an empty doc

Comment: Another question. What status code should I use if image property is missing? I'm using fetch on the client side and understand I need to use the same status code in more places.

Comment: I guess that depends on what can cause that to happen, but I would imagine you'd want one of the 400 errors:

http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
 Model.findById({image:{ $exists: true}}...
```